# Firebase crashlytics does not telling me the exact crash problem with swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I've already read a lot of questions about this on stack, but is there any solution to fix this to get the missing part of the crashreport?

[image]

I understand that these crashes were caused by some reason of nil or unwrapped options or something else, but crashes from objc are much better:

[image]

My project is based on objetive-c (started a few years ago) but the new big parts are written in swift. All crashes which are coming from the objc part are well detailed but those which are coming from the swift part not.

So the question is, how will I get readable crash reports instead of EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001028817ac

Comment: I understand the question but you're comparing two completely different types of crashes. In one case you're attempting to work with a nil value and the second case is accessing a specific array element that's out of bounds. The second case is much easier to manage and report on. What specifically are you looking for the crash report to indicate in the first example - what is 'missing part' do you need?

Comment: @Jay First of all, happy new year! So personally there is just one thing I don t understand about this error message, why isn t it much readable. Is there a way to get an error message like: "found nil while unwrapping an optional value" instead of exc_breakpoint. Because ofc I found the issue, and already fixed it, but it would be much nicer if there will be a detail message like that. Or this type of message always means this?

Comment: That's a common error and typically generated when force unwrapping optionals. You're probably doing something like `forUser: user!`.

Comment: ok thx. This error occured at the edge of the obj-c and swift code. There was an array in this case (objc side), and a force cast as! in the swift side in a for in, but when the array was empty it crashed

Answer (score 0):

For such cases, I would recommend adding advanced analytics of user behavior in the app and then try to repeat the same steps as the user. This will help to find the root of such crashes. I can share the code on the foundation of which you may add the necessary functionality on the screens of your app:

```
import Foundation
import Crashlytics

class EventLogger {

    /// Log a handled non-fatal exception
    class func logException(_ exception: NSException) {
        print("Catched exception: \(exception.debugDescription)")

        let frames = exception.callStackSymbols.map { symbol in CLSStackFrame(symbol: symbol) }
        Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordCustomExceptionName(exception.name.rawValue, reason: exception.reason, frameArray: frames)
    }

    private class func log(_ string: String) {
        CLSLogv(string, getVaList([]))
    }

    class func log(screen: String) {
        log("User is located at \(screen) Screen")
    }

    /// Log a status of feature
    class func log(feature: String, status: String) {
        log("Feature \(feature) was \(status)")
    }

    /// Log an event
    class func log(event: String) {
        log("Event: \(event)")
    }
}
```

and impement it like here:

```
EventLogger.log(event: "Pressed login button")
```

After the crash, you can see the action log exactly for this crash

Comment: the docs states that "This API is not intended be to used
 to log NSException objects" for the method recordCustomExceptionName()